# Cannot install Debian on QEmu-arm

Tags: system-installation, qemu

I'm trying to run Debian 6 network install with this command:

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel ./vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-versatile -initrd ./initrd.gz -hda ./debianlxde.img -m 256 -append "root=/dev/ram"
```

where kernel and initrd are taken from:

```
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-armel/current/images/versatile/netboot/initrd.gz
http://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armel/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-versatile
```

The installer runs but when it tries to recognize hard drives, it cannot.
My OS is Fedora 16, qemu-system-arm version is 0.15.1

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it give any errors?

Comment: Installator says that there is no hard drives and then nstallation fails

Comment: I think probem is `-hda ./debianlxde.img`, this image already exist?